# Magento 2 caching problem

Tags: magento-2.1, cache, varnish, redis

I am not able to flush the cache properly. I am using Magento 2.1.4, Redis and Varnish.

I have tried flushing the cache in the Magento admin: `Admin > System > Cache Management > Flush Cache Storage/Flush Magento Cache` and disabled all the caches.

I have purged my Varnish cache for my site: `curl –X PURGE http ://www.mysit e.com/`.

I have purged the Redis cache and FPC:

```
telnet redisxx.x xxxx
select 1
flushdb
```

Changed the mode to developer: `php-7.0 bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer` (from default)

Ran commands: `php-7.0 bin/magento setup:upgrade`, `php-7.0 bin/magento setup:di:compile` and `php-7.0 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`.

I have removed the content of the `pub/static/*` except the `.htaccess` file but still have the problem.

I have cleared my browser cache, used incognito mode, different browser and even a different machine.

Changes done in the code are not showing. I have even deleted a part of my site to see if that works but still nothing. If there anything else I can do? Why is the caching not flushing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitelisting my IP in in the DOS filter fixed this issue. There was a block on the load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming you **var** folder to something else. Most of the cache files are located either there or pub/static.
Also try  flushing cache from cli as below ;

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: See my answer! Thank you for your interest tho!